# writing the test cases for the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am new to the `react-redux`. Here I am trying to write a test case for a reducer.

so My reducer looks like ,

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
    Medium: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'MEDIUM'
        }
    ],
    High: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'TOUGH'
        }
    ]
}
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                Low: action.data,
                error: false,
            }
        case ADD_NEW:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.data.addtype]: action.data.addData,
                error: false,
            }
        case REMOVE_TECH:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.data.removeType]: action.data.newArr,
                error: false,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

In this, what happens is in the `add_new`,one more object gets added in the array with respective to the `type`.

So, the test case that I have written is like,

```
it("should add the new Row in the given type", () => {
      const addData = [{
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: 'CODE',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'},
            {
            id: 1,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: 'NON_CODE',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'
        }]
      const payload = { addtype: "Low", addData: addData};
      expect(LowLevelDataReducer(undefined, {
        type: ADD_NEW,
        data: payload
      })).toEqual(
        {
          ...initialState,
          [payload.addtype]: payload.addData,
          error: false
        }
      ) 
  })
```

Here `initialState` being the same.

So, is it the right  way to write this or wrong ?

Comment: You mean I dont need to do ...initialState

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the QuizData function and expect on the new state... You don't need to put the spread logic in your toEqual

let newstate=  QuizData({},payload)

expect(newstate.expectedProperty.value).toEqual(expectedValue)

Comment: Okay thanks for this, but will it be okay If I used the way I have used ?

Comment: no problem as such.. but you are bringing some logic into the test by  using spread syntax ..that's why i said.